# iam need this query from db

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

please help me to excute this query

```
 id    FDeviceName  FDeviceType
    1     case           mini
    2     rack           b
    3     amir           d  
    4     rack           a   
    5     case          max 
    6     case         mini
```

I want this query back

```
id    FDeviceName  FDeviceType      count
1     case           mini                2
2     rack           b                   1
3     amir           d                   1
4     rack           a                   1
5     case          max                  1
```

Comment: What sql-server version are you using? And what is the count based on is it both `FDeviceName` and `FDeviceType` or just `FDeviceType` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT id, FDeviceName, FDeviceType, COUNT(*)  FROM Table GROUP BY FDeviceName, FDeviceType
```

Comment: Will this exclude the row with the `id=6`? If you `group by id`?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MIN(id), FDeviceName, FDeviceType, Count(Id)
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY FDeviceName, FDeviceType
  ORDER BY 1;
```

should produce what you have demanded, assuming that id is a field